# How to use Rényi divergence for noise flooding

Tags: lattice-crypto

Let $\chi_\sigma$ be a discrete (or continuous) Gaussian distribution with standard deviation $\sigma$.
Then, it is known that for $y \in \mathbb{Z}$, a statistical distance between $\chi$ and $\chi + y$ is at most $|y|/\sigma$.
Similarly, I heard that there exists a similar result about Rényi divergence between $\chi$ and $\chi + y$.
The statistical distance provides us a noise flooding by choosing extremely large $\sigma$, which implies parameter inefficiency.

To overcome this limitation, some papers about lattice based cryptography deal with a noise flooding technique using the probability preservation of Rényi divergence even if the divergence is NOT small.

I have no idea how to control statistically close using the Rényi divergence.
As I understood, Rényi divergence is not metric, but it looks like a metric as intuitive sense. However, it is still hard for me how to show the statistically close of two distribution based on Rényi divergence.

Moreover, for distributions $\chi$ and $\chi + y$, if we want to set $\sigma$ to satisfy the statistical difference $2^{-k}$ using R`enyi divergence, how much large $\sigma$?

Comment: Could you link some of the papers that you talk about in the second paragraph?

Comment: @HilderVitorLimaPereira I leave two links 1) https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-319-72359-4_17 in Section 4.2
2) https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/769.pdf in Section 5

Comment: Have you seen [this work](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/480.pdf) by Prest? Section 3.3 in particular may be useful. Note that there are some nuances on whether one is working with a "search problem" or "decision problem".

Comment: @Mark Thank you. I also found this paper!.