# Noise flooding with Renyi divergence

Tags: provable-security, lattice-crypto, distinguisher, indistinguishability

According to [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/86802/how-to-use-r%C3%A9nyi-divergence-for-noise-flooding), I found papers that deal with noise flooding with Renyi divergence. However, the answer is still unclear to me on how to use Renyi divergence on the noise flooding technique.
For example, Section 5 in [this paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/769.pdf) provide a tight analysis for noise flooding by only showing $RD_2 (\chi_\alpha + y| \chi_\alpha) = poly(k)$ for some parameter $k$, where $\chi_\alpha$ is a discrete Gaussian distribution with the standard deviation $\alpha$ and $y$ is some error.
However, as a newbie in this field, I cannot fully understand why it is enough.
I think the main obstacle to my understanding is that distinguishing two distributions is a kind of `decision' problem, not a search problem.

My first thought is that the computatation might use the fact $\Pr_{v \leftarrow \chi_\alpha}[E(v)]\ge \Pr_{v\leftarrow \chi_\alpha + y}[E(v)]^2/RD_2$ for any event $E$. However, for the noise flooding technique which only means that $\chi_\alpha \approx \chi_\alpha + y$, what is the event $E$?
Even though there is an event $E$, the decision probability is usually of the form $1/2 + negl(k)$ where $negl$ is a negligible function. Thus, I think that $\Pr_{v \leftarrow \chi_\alpha}[E(v)] = 1/2 + negl(k)$. Thus, if $RD_2$ is $poly(k)$, the remaining probability could be smaller than $poly(k)/2 + poly(k)\cdot negl(k)>>1$, which implies that the bound is useless.

My second thought is to show that a distribution of LWE instance $(A, As + e)$ where $e\leftarrow \chi_\alpha$ and a distribution of LWE instance $(A,As + e^*)$ where $e^*\leftarrow \chi_\alpha+y$ is statistically close. However, for the noise flooding technique with the statistical distance, it does not need any LWE instances. Hence, I also guess that it might be a false approach.

How to correctly understand Renyi divergence for noise flooding?

Comment: This is what was analyzed in Section 3 of [this paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2022/816), although with slightly different language.

Comment: @Mark I briefly skim the paper that you link. As I thought, here $\alpha$ and $y$ correspond to $t$ and $ct.t$ in the paper. Thanks!